# What is the best apporach to create a Model class from DB table

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, model

I am trying to use a table suppose Account table from database containing 20 around columns and for different views I have requirement of different columns like for basic entries I need 10 columns for data insertion from one department and 5,5 from other departments. So, there will be 3 views who requires data or communicate between that table via Model So what will be the best approach to use:
1) Create 3 models like one contains only 10 columns and other 5-5?
2) Using only single model containing all columns. Isn't it gonna be carrying unnecessary data?

I know we can break that table and use relations to normalize data but I just want to understand more about the best approach like login Model and User Model. We can manage both with single model because we need username and password field for both but is it right way to use single model instead of 2?

Answer (score 0):

The Model and ViewModel represent separate concerns. Keep them separate. The entity should reflect the data state, where you can define view models to support the different view concerns. When you go to load the view models from the EF context via the Entities, you utilize `.Select()` which will compose efficient SQL queries for just the columns your view model will need.

For example, if I have an Account entity with 20-odd properties defined, but I want to present a list of Accounts listing just their User Names, last login time, and list of roles: (Which would be the "Name" property of a Role referenced by a AccountRoles table linking a many-to-many between accounts and roles)

```
[Serializable]
public class AccountSummaryViewModel
{
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDateTime { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Roles { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}


var accounts = MyContext.Accounts
    .Where(x => x.IsActive)
    .OrderBy(x => x.AccountName)
    .Select(x => new AccountSummaryViewModel
    {
        AccountName = x.AccountName,
        LastLoginDateTime = x.LastLoginDateTime,
        Roles = x.Roles.Select(x => x.Role.Name).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

The entity structure reflects your data structure, but then when the server go to query those entities to serve a view, define the ViewModel for the data structure you want to display and leverage EF to compose a query to fill that view model.

You can also leverage Automapper for this with it's `.ProjectTo<T>()` method which integrates with EF's `IQueryable` implementation.

EF DbContexts can also only have one entity registered that is associated to a single table. To have multiple flavors of entity pointing at an Account table, you would need multiple DbContext definitions. Bounded contexts are useful for large systems, but can lead to miserably intertwined context references if used improperly.

It is advisable to avoid ever passing entities to a view because this can lead to all kinds of performance issues, exceptions, as well as security vulnerabilities, especially if controllers actions accept entities back from the client.  By passing entities to a client The service is passing more information to the client than it needs, and you run into potential issues around triggering lazy loading calls, or tripping up the serialization with circular references. The system also tell hackers/competitors more about your data structure and data than it really should be. The UI may not display most of the information in the entity, but it is sending all of that data to the client. This requires more memory on the server/client, and larger payloads over the wire as well.